# 2D heat equation with BC as zeroes ( Solved completely: no need to answer this)

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, sturm-liouville

[image]

I need help with this question, I dont know what is wrong with this problem or is there any typo in the original question,
By using $$u(x,y,t)=X(x)Y(y)T(t)$$
I am getting $$X(x)=0$$ which yields $$u(x,y,t)=0$$, But that should not be the case. All of trouble I am getting is because of the third boundary condition $u_x(a,y,t)=0$. What I feel it should be $u(a,y,t)=0$ instead of that $u_x$

Let me know how you will solve the question and obtain and non-zero answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you replace your guess $u(x, y, t) = X(x) Y(y) T(t)$ in the equation you'll get

$$
\frac{1}{X}\frac{{\rm d}^2X}{{\rm d}x^2} + \frac{1}{Y}\frac{{\rm d}^2Y}{{\rm d}x^2} = \frac{1}{\alpha^2 T}\frac{{\rm d}T}{{\rm d}t} = -k^2
$$

The sign of the constant just comes from the fact that a non-negative constant will make the temperature exponentially increase with time. So you have the equation

$$
\frac{1}{X}\frac{{\rm d}^2X}{{\rm d}x^2} = -k^2 - \frac{1}{Y}\frac{{\rm d}^2Y}{{\rm d}x^2} = -n^2
$$

or equivalentely

$$
\frac{1}{X}\frac{{\rm d}^2X}{{\rm d}x^2} = -n^2, ~~~~ \frac{1}{Y}\frac{{\rm d}^2Y}{{\rm d}Y^2} = -m^2, ~~~~ n^2 + m^2 = k^2
$$

The solutions of these are fairly straightforward, e.g.

$$
X(x) = A \cos n x + B \sin n x
$$

with the conditions

\begin{eqnarray}
X'(0) &=& 0 = -A n \sin (n\cdot 0) + B n \cos (n \cdot 0) = B n ~~~\Rightarrow~~~ B = 0 \\
X'(a) &=& 0 = -A n \sin (n\cdot a) = 0
\end{eqnarray}

This last equation has two possible solutions: $A = 0$, which makes $X(x) = 0$ and therefore $u(x, y, t) = 0$. And the other solution is

$$
n = \frac{n_x \pi}{a} ~~\mbox{for}~~~ n_x = 0, 1,\cdots
$$

You can repeat the analysis for $Y(y)$

Comment: Thanks.. but yesterday I already solved it completely..but still I appreciate your help.. I just logged in mathstack account

Comment: @AmanRajput If this looks like a correct solution, then activate the check mark next to this answer to accept it as a solution.

Comment: okay .... but i already solved it .. let me tick it